# Showing integral exists

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am having a hard time seeing how the following is calculated:

Consider $f:[1,\infty] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}, \text{ for } n \leq x \leq n+1.$

Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}f = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}.$$

I considered defining the following:

$$f_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\chi_{[k,k+1]}.$$

Then using the Monotone Convergence Theorem, however, the $\{f_n\}$ are not non-negative...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at $$\int_1^nf=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1}f=\sum_k^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $a_n:=\int_1^n f$ for all $n$, so $a_1=0, a_2=-1, a_3=-1+\frac{1}{2},$ etc. If you have to show only the existence of the limit, it is sufficient to see that
$$
\forall n \ge 1, \quad 
\int_{2n}^{2n+2}f=a_{2n+2}+a_{2n+1}=-\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n} \in \left[0,\frac{1}{n^2}\right].
$$
In particular, you can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem at the sequence of functions $(f \chi_{[1,2n]}: n\ge 1)$.